# React Native & Firebase : user info not being stored in database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux

I'm trying to create a new user and store their information in firebase database. I successfully create the user but the user information isn't getting stored in firebase.

The function that is running is `handleAuthWithFirebase`

The `console.log("Storing user")` is showing up in the console so I'm not sure why `firebase.database().ref().set` isn't running.

Here is my code

```js
export function handleAuthWithFirebase (newUser) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(authenticating());

        console.log(newUser);
        console.log('Signing up user');
        var email = newUser.email;
        var password = newUser.password;

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
        }).then(() => {

            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            // Set user in Firebase
            console.log("Storing user")
            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).set({
                name: newUser.displayName,
                username: newUser.username,
                email: newUser.email
            })
        }).then(() => {
            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            dispatch(isAuthed(user.uid))
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing a child object, so you have to specify it after ref. It would be more helpful if you can post the tree of your database as well, but before try this and figure out yout child.

```
     firebase.database().ref('myRef').child('myChild').set({
                name: newUser.displayName,
                username: newUser.username,
                email: newUser.email
     })
```

Comment: I tried `firebase.database().ref('/users/').child(user.uid).set()` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got working, for those coming across this post.

```js
firebaseApp.auth()
            .createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(response => {

                firebaseApp.database().ref('users').child(response.user.uid).set({
                    firstName: this.state.firstName,
                    lastName: this.state.lastName,
                    username: this.state.username,
                    email: this.state.email
                });

                response.user.sendEmailVerification().then(response => {
                    AlertIOS.alert('Message', 'Sending email verification to '+this.state.email)
                });
                this.setState({authenticating: false})
            }, error => {
                AlertIOS.alert('Error', error.message);
                this.setState({authenticating: false})
            })
```